# 2019 Requirements - LTS release versions

Tags: cobalt

2019 CE Certification Requirements are referring to LTS:

The target device ​MUST​ run a version that is not older than the Cobalt 2019 LTS release (LTS = Long Term Support)

Is Build 11 already LTS release? Will all subsequent releases be LTS?

Thank you.

Comment: Colour me bemused by how many users, and in some cases developers, think it's a good idea to farm out to SO the asking/answering of strictly support questions with no reference to programming. Does Cobalt say to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a support question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

For the Cobalt community rules: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cobalt-dev/lwH3cKoECJs

To answer your question, Cobalt 11 is compliant for the YouTube 2018 Technical Requirements. Cobalt 2019 LTS version is not released yet. For the YouTube specific technical requirements and certification related questions, please work with your YouTube technical account manager.

Comment: Thank you Daniel.